# Adding XML Schema Reference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I can't find for the life of me if it's possible to add a direct reference to the schema in the root of my XML.

Here is my code:

```
Declare @Employee table (EmployeeID int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50))
    Insert into @Employee values
    (1,'John','Smith'),
    (2,'Jane','Doe'  )


    Select (Select CreatedBy='My Organization',CreateDate=GetDate() For XML Path('RecordHeader'),Type ) 
          ,(Select * From @Employee For XML Path('Employee'),Type ) 
    For XML Path ('Employees'),Type
```

Which produces the following results:

```
<Employees>
  <RecordHeader>
    <CreatedBy>My Organization</CreatedBy>
    <CreateDate>2016-10-18T16:09:48.110</CreateDate>
  </RecordHeader>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>John</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Is there a way to add part in my SQL to make the root tag to include the following:

```
<Employees xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always had trouble with xmlns, so I use a little hack

```
Declare @Employee table (EmployeeID int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50))
Insert into @Employee values
(1,'John','Smith'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  )

Declare @XML xml = (
Select (Select CreatedBy='My Organization',CreateDate=GetDate() For XML Path('RecordHeader'),Type ) 
      ,(Select * From @Employee For XML Path('Employee'),Type ) 
For XML Path ('Employees'),Type
)

set @XML.modify('insert ( attribute MyNameSpace {"https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd"}) into (/Employees)[1]')
set @XML = replace(cast(@XML as nvarchar(max)),'[MyNameSpace]','xmlns')

Select @XML
```

Returns

```
<Employees xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
  <RecordHeader>
    <CreatedBy>My Organization</CreatedBy>
    <CreateDate>2017-01-10T15:19:42.873</CreateDate>
  </RecordHeader>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>John</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

> **EDIT to Exclude Empty Values**

NULL will be omitted by default, so if you want to exclude empty values (not null), You can convert the value to NULL via NullIf().  For example

```
Declare @Employee table (EmployeeID int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50))
Insert into @Employee values
(1,'John','Smith'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ),
(3,'Betty',null  ),  -- No element for Last_Name
(4,'Susan',''  )     -- No element for Last_Name

Declare @XML xml = (
Select (Select CreatedBy='My Organization',CreateDate=GetDate() For XML Path('RecordHeader'),Type ) 
      ,(Select EmployeeID = NullIf(EmployeeID,'') 
              ,First_Name = NullIf(First_Name,'')
              ,Last_Name  = NullIf(Last_Name,'')
         From  @Employee For XML Path('Employee'),Type ) 
For XML Path ('Employees'),Type
)

set @XML.modify('insert ( attribute MyNameSpace {"https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd"}) into (/Employees)[1]')
set @XML = replace(cast(@XML as nvarchar(max)),'[MyNameSpace]','xmlns')

Select @XML
```

Comment: Thank you John! You come through as usual!

Comment: @ssokol91 Happy it helpled

Comment: I don't know a direct way either... +1 from my side. One tiny hint: Better to cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the XML is 16-bit encoded internally and - besides performance - VARCHAR might mess up some special characters... And one idea: It might be easier to use `STUFF` to replace the starting `<Employees>` with `<Employees xmlsn="blah">` on string base...

Comment: @Shnugo I was hoping you would weigh-in.. Fair point on the nvarchar.  Why is xmlns blocked from a direct update?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I don't know, it seems silly... My assumption is, that internally the XML is handled quite similar to the result if one calls `FROM OPENXML` (or from your *super-heavy-weight*-great-function). Changing the **default** namespace might have high and unpredictable impact...

Comment: Thanks! You guys are great. Not to start a new topic, what would be the most efficient way to remove or exclude empty results to prevent empty tags such as <BlahTag />? 
Tks again!

Comment: @ssokol91 See updated / edit.   Nulls will be omitted by default, so you can null empty values via NullIf()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WITH NAMESPACES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) keyword, but that adds the name space to all the nodes:

```
Declare @Employee table (EmployeeID int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50))
Insert into @Employee values
(1,'John','Smith'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  );


WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd')
Select (Select CreatedBy='My Organization',CreateDate=GetDate() For XML Path('RecordHeader'),Type ) 
      ,(Select * From @Employee For XML Path('Employee'),Type ) 
For XML Path ('Employees'),Type
```

Result:

```
<Employees xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
  <RecordHeader xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
    <CreatedBy>My Organization</CreatedBy>
    <CreateDate>2017-01-10T16:36:23.450</CreateDate>
  </RecordHeader>
  <Employee xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>John</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee xmlns="https://www.blahblah.org/blahblah/BlahSchema.xsd">
    <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
    <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it looks like it adds it to every parent tag instead of the root. Tks!